# The development server returned response error code: 500 (React Native)

Tags: react-native, npm

After installing the following libraries:

1. @react-navigation/native
2. @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

I started receiving the error: The development server returned response error code: 500 (React Native). I tried a lot but could not figure out what is the reason.

Can somebody help to figure it out?

Comment: are you using expo?

Answer (score 0):

Delete babel-preset-react-native folder inside node_modules and then install older version 2.1.0 of this library with npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev

Comment: babel-preset-fbjs
babel-preset-jest
This are the only folders in node_mdoules.

Comment: delete the package from pakeage.json and install the version it will help.